# What makes a CPU architecture "X-bit"?

Tags: cpu, bit, cpu-architecture

**Warning:** I'm not sure where this type of question belongs. If you know a better place for it, drop a link.

**Background:** Imagine you heard a sentence like this: "this computer/processor has X-bit architecture". Now, if that computer is standard, you get a lot of information, like maximum RAM capacity, maximum unsigned/signed integer value and so on... But what if computer is not standard?

**The mystery:** back to 70's and 80's, the period referred as "8-bit era". Wait, 8-bit? Yes. So, if a CPU architecture is 8-bit, then:

- The maximum RAM capacity of computer is exactly 256 bytes.
- The maximum UInt range is from 0 to 256 and the maximum signed integer range is -128 to 127.
- The maximum ROM capacity is also 256 bytes, because you have to be able to jump around?

However, it's clearly not like that. Look at some technical characteristics of game consoles of that time and you will see that those exceed the 256 limit.

Quotes (http://www.8bitcomputers.co.uk/whatbasics.html):

> The Sharp PC1211 is actually a 4-bit computer but cleverly glues two together to look like 8 (a computer able to add up to 16 would not be very useful!)

So if it's a 4-bit computer, why can manipulate 8-bit integers? And another one...

> The Sinclair QL is one of those computers that actually leaves the experts arguing. In parts, it is a 16 bit computer, in some ways it is even like a 32 bit computer but it holds its memory in 8 bits.

What? So why is this mess in www.*8bitcomputers*.co.uk?

**Generally:** how is an X-bit computer defined?

- The biggest data bus that it has is X bits long (then Sinclair QL is a 32-bit computer)?
- The CU functions of that computer are X bits long?
- It holds its memory (in registers, ROM, RAM, whatever) in 8 bits?
- Other definitions?

**Purpose:** I think that what I am designing is a 4-bit CPU. I don't really know if it has a 4-bit architecture, because it uses double ROM address, and includes functions like "activate ALU" that take another 4 bits from register Y. I want to know if I can still call it a 4-bit CPU. That's it!
Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: I believe an X-bit computer has a maximum RAM capacity of 2^X bytes. Other than that, I think this is off topic, possibly belonging on [su], though I'm not really sure. Maybe a more electronics related site would be better ([electronics.se]?), see [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) for a list.

Comment: Thank You so much! Heading to those sites. And also thanks for the RAM capacity thought, if it's true, then I can make huge ROM and my 4-bit (which I will be able to call 4-bit) computer will be able to run tick-tack-toe! Thanks!

Comment: Actually I think I am wrong about the 2^X limit - [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier).

Comment: Perhaps, as Grad said "The addressing doesn't matter in defining the number X. An 8-bit computer  can have 16-bit addressing in order to increase the RAM or memory size.
An X-bit computer (or CPU) is defined whether the central unites and registers, such as CPU and ALU, are in X-bit." Yet, by his definition, I'm still designing a 4-bit computer! And now I'm learning of exactly what parts CPU is made of.

Comment: Just in case it helps you, you could read the spec on the 4004, intels first microprocessor :) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An X-bit computer (or CPU) is defined whether the central unites and registers, such as CPU and ALU, are in X-bit. The addressing doesn't matter in defining the number X. As you have mentioned, an 8-bit computer (e.g. Motorola 68HC11 even tough it is a MCU, still it can be counted as a computer with CPU, I/O and Memory) can have 16-bit addressing in order to increase the RAM or memory size.

The data-bus size and the register sizes of CPU and ALU is the limiting factor in defining the  X number in an X-bit computer architecture. You can get more information from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)

An answer to your question will be "Yes, you are designing a 4-bit CPU if the registers and data bus size are in 4-bit.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer! I can't believe I missed that article, I'm definetly going to read it right now. So, you're saying that @Dukeling is incorrect? I always thought that MMU is a part of CPU (along with ALU and CU)! And if my CPU takes instruction "activate GPU" and the GPU takes information of all 4 registers (coordinate X, coordinate Y, character, color), with an overal instruction length of 4*5=20 bits, the computer is still 4-bit?

Comment: A 4-bit computer takes its instructions as 4-bit size. This configuration can be changed if there are different specialized instructions. However, activate GPU and taking coordinates from GPU should be different instructions I guess. As a last comment, if your processing unit processes 4-bit words, yes, it is still a 4-bit computer.

Comment: Can a 4-bit computer have 4 data buses of 4 bits? For example, program that emits single character on the screen would be written like this: loading variables to registers, then command to activate the GPU, then GPU takes the loaded 4-bit variables from registers, which determine what function (out of 16) GPU will be doing, to what coordinates (out of 16+16=32) the character written in register 4 (16 possible characters) will be put on the screen. I believe that this is that **different specialized instruction!**

Comment: Or, the same example would be with addition program: load operand 1 to register 1, then operand 2 to register 2, then functions (say ADD) to register 3, and then CPU gets instruction to activate ALU, which takes all three arguments and stores the result to the register 4. The whole instruction is 16bit long (CPU function, operand 1, operand 2, ALU function), yet all arguments and functions are 4 bit long! Can it be done by a 4-bit computer? That's my last question in this question, I swear!

Comment: Yes, it can be done by 4-bit computer. Please check Motorola 68HC11's user manual and programming guide as an example. (It's 8-bit as I said earlier)

Here is an example code for adding the numbers in addresses $1003 and $1004:

`LDAA $1004;
ADDA $1003`

So, the whole instructions cover 32 bits, or 4 bytes; however, they are entered as separate 4-bit instructions.